# "Быть не в первых, а в последних" — нужен ли дефис?

Tags: орфография

Нужен ли дефис: "Быть не в первых, а в последних"?

Answer (score 3):

Если не в первых, а в последних, например, рядах, то  дефис не нужен, т.к. это не наречия, в которых при наличии приставки ВО-(В-) и суффиксов -ЫХ(-ИХ)дефис должен быть. В слове "(в)последних" дефис возможен, если подводится итог сказанному: во-первых..., во-вторых... и в-последних:...Хотя так, мне кажется, говорят редко.

Comment: Я тоже так считаю, а учитель ставит дефис.  ???